# How do I fix './mainnet.sh status' reporting wrong status of docker containers?

Tags: docker, tezos-client

After updating to latest `mainnet.sh` and latest docker images (I think - I have no idea where to look for the version number) and restarting the docker containers, `./mainnet.sh status` fails to report correct status of the docker containers.

`docker ps` returns:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                                  PORTS                                            NAMES
40854a0f194e        tezos/tezos:mainnet                  "/usr/local/bin/entr…"   10 seconds ago      Up 1 second                                                                              mainnet_endorser-003-PsddFKi3_1_5e47d7508fcd
afb6b9e258bf        tezos/tezos:mainnet                  "/usr/local/bin/entr…"   10 seconds ago      Up 6 seconds                                                                             mainnet_accuser-003-PsddFKi3_1_c35841fd2f77
fed812d9eaf9        tezos/tezos:mainnet                  "/usr/local/bin/entr…"   10 seconds ago      Up 7 seconds                                                                             mainnet_baker-003-PsddFKi3_1_fefc704f16d2
502f84078be8        tezos/tezos:mainnet                  "/usr/local/bin/entr…"   11 seconds ago      Up 9 seconds                            0.0.0.0:8732->8732/tcp, 0.0.0.0:9732->9732/tcp   mainnet_node_1_10f0fd5baed5
```

But `./mainnet.sh status` returns:

```
Node is not running
Baker is running
Error: No such container: mainnet_baker-003-PsddFKi3_1
The current baker is not the latest available.
Endorser is running
Error: No such container: mainnet_endorser-003-PsddFKi3_1
The current endorser is not the latest available.
The script is up to date.
```

How do I fix it so `./mainnet status` reports correct status of the containers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out to be a specific issue with `docker-compose` version `1.23.0` and `1.23.1`, where containers get hashes appended to their names when running them (source: [this serverfault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/938050/how-to-prevent-docker-compose-appending-hashes-to-created-container-names)).

This turns eg. `mainnet_baker-003-PsddFKi3_1` into `mainnet_baker-003-PsddFKi3_1_fefc704f16d2`.

The solution is to **upgrade `docker-compose` to version `1.23.3`or higher** and just restart your containers with the `./mainnet.sh` script.